# JavaScript data attributes and dataset confusion

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I saw a video about creating tabs using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. But I am not understanding how the code is working. This is a codepen of the code: [Tabs Codepen by WebDevSimplified](https://codepen.io/WebDevSimplified/pen/ewapgK). To be more specific I am not understanding what the value of `target` will be in this line `const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget);`. Is it taking the values `#home`, `#pricing` and `#about` from `data-tab-target` and applying the class active on the specific `data-tab-content` based on which `data-tab-target` the user clicks on?

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]');
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]');

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget);
    tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
      tabContent.classList.remove('active');
    })
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
      tab.classList.remove('active');
    })
    tab.classList.add('active');
    target.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
[data-tab-content] {
    display: none;
}
  
.active[data-tab-content] {
    display: block;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.tabs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.tab {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}

.tab.active {
    background-color: #CCC;
}

.tab:hover {
    background-color: #AAA;
}

.tab-content {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li data-tab-target="#home" class="active tab">Home</li>
    <li data-tab-target="#pricing" class="tab">Pricing</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" data-tab-content class="active">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>This is the home</p>
    </div>
    <div id="pricing" data-tab-content>
        <h1>Pricing</h1>
        <p>Some information on pricing</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code should be in the question, not behind a link.

Comment: Sounds like a good use for `console.log`.

Comment: Please add relevant code here as a [mcve], as an [edit] to your question, not links to off-site resources.

Comment: So on the element, it's retrieving the id selector of the associated element from `data-tab-target` as it iterates through the tabs in the foreach then toggling the css classes as it goes along. Not sure what else you're looking for but like Scott pointed out, console logging or setting breakpoints in the dev tools debugger explains as it goes pretty well.

Comment: Added the code to the question

Comment: @ChrisW. I tried console logging but nothing is shown in the dev tools console I don't know why. I tried some stuff in chrome and firefox dev tools but I don't know where it shows what values the variable is taking. I am not sure how to set breakpoints.

Comment: So if you were to put `console.log(tab.dataset.tabTarget);` inside your event handler method (like above the `const = document....`) then in the console you should see that the value passed is the value of the `data-tab-target` attribute of the tab you clicked. Which is the id selector (eg; #pricing) of the tab to display and will apply the css of `display: block` to make that content appear. Beyond that I may not be sure what you're asking?

Comment: Ok thank you, I was thinking it's more complicated than what it is for no reason. I finally understood. I put `console.log` inside the event listener which only logs something to the console only when I click one of the tabs and I got confused when nothing was getting logged when I went live on VS Code.